# filter array of objects by comparing string property with another array elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

Suppose I have array of objects as `rows` below and `wantedBrands` is a array of strings.

```
let rows = [
            { name: "Russia", brands: ['XM1', 'XM2', 'XM3'] },
            { name: "Italy", brands: ['XM4', 'XM5', 'XM6'] }
           ];

let wantedBrands = ['XM5'];

let result = rows.filter(row => row.brands.some(b => wantedBands.includes(b)));
            
console.log(result);
```

I get result as follows because it checks which row elements has `wantedBrands` in it and filters accordingly

```
[
    { "name": "Italy", "brands": [ "XM4", "XM5", "XM6" ] }
]
```

Here is my problem. So instead of `brands` property in the array of objects being an array of strings, it will just be a single brand with one string element.

```
let rows = [
            { name: "Russia", brands: 'XM1' },
            { name: "Italy", brands: 'XM5' },
            { name: "Turkey", brands: 'XM5' }
];
```

I want result as follows. how do I achieve this result

```
[
    { name: "Italy", brands: 'XM5' },
    { name: "Turkey", brands: 'XM5' }

]
```

Comment: What should the result be if `brands` is `['XM5', 'XM6']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go **:**

```js
let rows = [
  { name: "Russia", brands: 'XM1' },
  { name: "Italy", brands: 'XM5' },
  { name: "Turkey", brands: 'XM5' }
];

let wantedBrands = ['XM5'];

const res = rows.filter(({ brands }) => wantedBrands.includes(brands));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

For each row check if `wantedBrands` includes the brand

```js
const rows = [{
    name: "Russia",
    brands: 'XM1'
  },
  {
    name: "Italy",
    brands: 'XM5'
  },
  {
    name: "Turkey",
    brands: 'XM5'
  }
];

const wantedBrands = ['XM5'];

const result = rows.filter(row => wantedBrands.includes(row.brands));

console.log(result);
```